# Canvas doesn't refresh unless the WPF Window is moved

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics

I have a simple WPF Window with a Canvas on it and the Canvas has a Path object with a GeometryGroup inside the Path:

```
<Path
      Stroke="Red"
      StrokeThickness="3">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup Children="{Binding Elements}" />
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

So I initialize the Elements collection before the `InitializeComponent()` call and it shows up correctly. After that using a `System.Timers.Timer` I update the existing shape's points so they move. This works. But the problem is I only see the Canvas updating its result when the WPF Window is moved by a mouse. If I leave it there, then the last image just hangs there but the points are updated.

I can see this when I start moving the WPF Window again and the Shapes jump to their latest location.

Any ideas on how to fix this and why it's doing it?

Comment: I'm guessing U did ur delegate to handle the UI thread, if not it will throw error. Correct me if i'm wrong, but using System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer might be better as it invoke on the UI thread directly

Comment: Yes I am doing like you said, so it works, but I need to do the calculations on another thread and the update the UI. I only update Elements but that still requires it to be done in the UI thread.

Comment: ok, want to try this? For canvas, I believe these is something like canvas.left. Do a simple 1. After U do ur calculation, try to change the value of canvas.left from your calculation thread. If u can call the object, try doing an invoke. Example is shown here : http://cskardon.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/invoking-ui-changes-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the class you're binding to, and the list of items should implement INotifyCollectionChanged, like ObservableCollection. Once you do that, timers or dispatchers are not needed.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using the Timer because of that. This is like a game like application where the calculations has to be on a separate thread running at regular intervals to evaluate the game world. Also I can't use ObservableCollection because GeometryGroup.Children requires GeometryCollection.

Comment: @Joan, I haven touch WPF for quite a while, but if I can recall ObservableCollection is very useful. I remembered using ObservableCollection to tie to a custom class. So if values from the custom changed, UI gets updated